# combinatorics how to choose r?

Tags: combinatorics

i started learning combinatorics for competitive programming and i faced a problem as follow

**Given a string S of N $0$'s and M $1$'s, how many unique permutations of this string start with 1?**

thee answer to this problem is supposed to be choose(N+M-1,N) but i was wondering why N ? why not M ? if i can choose of n+m-1 positions how many ways can i arrange 1s shouldn't it also work how many ways can i arrange 0s?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, that works, too, but that doesn’t yield $\binom{N+M-1}N$, but $\binom{N+M-1}{M-1}$, since only $M-1$ of the $1$s remain to be arranged (the $M$-th being fixed at the start of the string). And $\binom{N+M-1}{M-1}=\binom{N+M-1}N$.